# how to post a message on a friends facebook wall using c# sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

using facebook c# sdk, I'm able to post to my wall but when I try to do it on my friend's wall, it just does not show, any ideas why this could be happening?

this works

`client.Post("me/feed", parameters);`

this does not work

`client.Post("friends id/feed", parameters);`

`client.Post("/friends id/feed", parameters);`

Comment: See Feb 2013 changes: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed on the server side, use fb.ui and wallpost dialog for this purpose.

Per the [February 2013 completed changes from FB](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/).

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>   We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph
>   API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is
>   different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the
>   target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you
>   want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the
>   feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or
>   action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the
>   friend approves the tag). For more info, see [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/).

From the blog:

> Post to friends wall via the API generate a high levels of negative
>   user feedback, including “Hides” and “Mark as Spam" and so we are
>   removing it from the API. If you want to allow people to post to their
>   friend’s timeline from your app, you can invoke the feed dialog.
>   Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action
>   tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend
>   approves the tag).

Comment: @Baran: A key part of this site is providing depth in your answers in order to help not just the OP but others that are seeing the same issue.  Although you were technically correct in how to resolve the issue, you provided no detail as to why the problem existed to begin with.  In the future please try and provide more detail.